# Protecting thunderbirds logins.json

Tags: password, thunderbird, apparmor

When I start thunderbird, it reads the encrypted passwords from logins.json and asks me for the master password.
But I feel that using a local master password for this file is not the right way.
Is there a way to remove the master password from logins.json and protect the file with system tools so that only /usr/bin/thunderbird can access it?
Can apparmor do this?